# How do I make a div with guide lines?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to make a div with horizontal and vertical guide lines, it will be also draggable, this is my current fiddle I'm working on:

Just to Clarify:

I don't want only the border of the div, but to occupy the entire document.

http://jsfiddle.net/y59fL/2/

How can I make it work? I'm working only with the left side by now, then I just will do the same for the other sides...

This is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="demo">

<div id="draggable-block" class="draggable">
    <div class="left-guideline">  
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; font-size: .9em;}
.block { 
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    overflow: visible;
}

.left-guideline {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}

#snaptarget { height: 80px; }

body, html{
  background: url('http://puu.sh/6Bksm.png') repeat;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);  
}
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable-block").draggable({
        grid: [10, 10]
    });
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, it works in the fiddle. you just need to add the border to all sides? `border: 1px solid #000000;`

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here? because from the fiddle, it seems to be working as you explained.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/huKEh/?

Comment: I want to add a line that is 100% height for the left side, not only the size of the div :/

Comment: I think you'll need to use the drag event to position a helper element for the ruler lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but it seems that the draggable block is not properly aligned with the grid, and it does not start in the upper left corner. To fix these issues, you need to account for the borders in the size of the draggable box like this:

```
.block { 
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 98px;
    width: 98px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and you need to remove the margin from the body element to align the block with the upper left corner like this:

```
body, html{
  background: url('http://puu.sh/6Bksm.png') repeat;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here is a link to a fiddle with the above corrections: http://jsfiddle.net/y59fL/3/

Edit after comment:

A new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y59fL/10/

Comment: how to do the border lines to be 100% height and width with the body, not with the div?

Comment: yea, it's exactly that but, can you see the scrollbar how reduced it is because of the 10000px height and -5000px top? isn't there a way to do it with 100%?

Comment: I don't think so. Not without using javascript to update the height of the guide-line, and if you are doing that, it would be easier to just position the guide using javascript. Would it be possible to just set overflow hidden on the container element? Here is a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/y59fL/15/

Comment: Oh, i just set the body with overflow: hidden and that solved the problem :) Thanks mate!